# Configuring Cakephp routes

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I have built a simple app. I want to configure the routes to something like this.

```
 domain_name.com/@username 

 Router::connect('/@*', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

But it does not work. It gives error page cannot be found. Is there anyway i can get **domain.com/@username** to work.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: The @ is a special character in URLs. I don't think you can get it to work without URL-encoding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Story has posted an excellent article on how to achieve this using Custom Routing classes in CakePHP 1.3.  You definitely don't need to use the @ symbol to achieve this if you follow this guide.  Hope this helps.

[Using custom Route classes in CakePHP](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp)